# Javascript: Is there something different with Node.prototype? For some reason I cant modify it without errors

Tags: javascript, prototype, nodes

I'm currently trying to write a userscript for an online browser game by modifying prototypes (the code is encrypted, so this is the only way i can do it). Usually what I'll do is something like this:

```
var fillz = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fill;
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fill = function(){
    var arguments_ = arguments;

    // based on the extension, modify arguments_ as needed

    fillz.apply(this, arguments_);
};
```

Recently, I needed to make some edits to Node.prototype.appendChild. But for some reason, the base code here:

```
var appndchld = Node.prototype.appendChild;
Node.prototype.appendChild = function(){
    appndchld.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

keeps throwing errors. As far as I can tell, it should never throw errors because I haven't even made any edits yet.

Any insight? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns a value, so if any part of the code expects the function to return a value, then it will fail.

You need to change our code so that it will return the value of the original call:

```
var appndchld = Node.prototype.appendChild;
Node.prototype.appendChild = function(){
   return appndchld.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You should always assume that the function you overwrite has a return value and use `return` in your wrapper. And even if it does not have one I would still add the `return`, because it will make it save to for the case that the function will have a return value in future.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for the tip! ;D for some reason, i guess i've never had to overwrite something that used the return value, so it never occurred to me. :P